# Printf %X identifier - Weird behaviour with pointers

Tags: c++, c, printf

I was recently in an interview and was given the question:

---

Look at this code and write its output:

```
unsigned char buff[] = { 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33, 0x33 };
unsigned long *pD = (unsigned long *)buff;
unsigned short *pS = (unsigned short *)buff;
void *pEnd = &buff[sizeof(buff) - 1];

for (; pD < pEnd; pD++)
    printf("0x%X\n", *pD);

for (; pS < pEnd; pS++)
    printf("0x%X\n", *pS);

return 0;
```

---

Now assuming the system is 32bits and unsigned long is 4 bytes, the answer is:

- 0x11111111
- 0x22222222
- 0x33333333
- 0x1111
- 0x1111
- 0x2222
- 0x2222
- 0x3333
- 0x3333

### Now for my question:

Why does it print only 16 bits with the unsigned short variable?
I know that unsigned short is 2 bytes but printf knows how much bytes to parse from the stack based on the %X, which is read as unsigned int. I would assume that it will read 4 bytes (unsigned int) at all times, with sometimes junk (or corrupted stack eventually).

What do you think?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that technically, passing an `unsigned long` to a `"%X"` specifier is undefined behavior.  It will work on most 32 bit systems (although one could easily imagine an implementation where it didn't), but will cause problems on most 64 bit systems.

Comment: And whoever asks this in an interview clearly isn't very competent himself.

Comment: `unsigned long *pD = (unsigned long *)buff;` potentially suffers from alignment issues and could fail on various platforms.  `unsigned short *pS = ...` also.

Comment: @James Kanze `unsigned long` to a `"%X"` specifier also fails whenever `sizeof(int) < sizeof(long)` as with a 16-bit `int` and 32-bit `long`, common in 2014 in embedded systems.

Comment: @chux Yes.  I just mentioned the most frequent case for the average user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*pS` is of type unsigned short, so this value is used. Though printf expects an int for %X, you provide an unsigned short, which is promoted to int. So the order is: first 2 bytes are read from your array because *pS is unsigned short. Then this unsigned short value is promoted to int.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have pointers in the output. By dereferencing you're telling printf to output a short and that's what it does. %X only displays that as hex.

Comment: `printf` has no idea what type you passed it.  Passing it the wrong type is undefined behavior (but in the case of `unsigned short`, integral promotion occurs, so the type is correct).